# Airflow - Dynamic task mapping and Multi output Xcoms

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

In Airflow (2.7.1) I would like to use the output of a task with multiple_outputs in a dynamic task mapping call:

```
@task(multiple_outputs=multiple_outputs)
def get_variable_key(variable):
    return Variable.get(variable, deserialize_json=deserialize_json)

settings = get_variable_key('my_var')

run_crawlers = GlueCrawlerOperator.partial(
    task_id='run_crawlers',
    wait_for_completion=True).expand(config=settings['glue_crawlers_config'])
```

But doing so results in an error: "cannot map over XCom with custom key"
Looking a the code, it seems like *expand* only accepts *XCOM_RETURN_KEY* (in mappedoeprator ensure_xcomarg_return_value). So if I do this:

```
@task
def retrieve_glue_crawlers_config(settings):
    return settings['glue_crawlers_config']

run_crawlers = GlueCrawlerOperator.partial(
    task_id='run_crawlers',
    wait_for_completion=True).expand(config=retrieve_glue_crawlers_config(settings))
```

it works, but it seems a bit convoluted and ineficient. Is there a better way to handle this?